# Why does zu not effect declensions sometime?

Tags: declension

I've noticed that many times when we have "zu viel X" then the viel is not declined. Another example I found:

> Moderne Industriegesellschaften sind getrieben von einem "Zuviel" das die unterschiedlichsten Facetten hat: ein Übermaß an Informationen, **ein zu grosses Warenangebot**, zu viel Nahrung, um nur einige zu nennen.

Even as a dative preposition it has no effect on the declension of gross in the above!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Zu* has many functions beside being a preposition requiring dative.

If it is used with the meaning of English *too* as in *too big*, it does not change the case of the following adjectives and noun:

Nom.: Ein großes Warenangebot - Ein zu großes Warenangebot
Gen.: Eines großen Warenangebots - Eines zu großen Warenangebots
Dat.: Einem großen Warenangebot - Einem zu großen Warenangebot
Akk.: Ein großes Warenangebot - Ein zu großes Warenangebot

When used in this way, *zu* immediately precedes the adjective it modifies, not the article as the preposition *zu* would.

Answer (score 1):

*Zu* is only a dative preposition where it resembles English *to+noun phrase*. If you combine it with a verb phrase it does not command dative for example. As verbs do not have cases.

And it doesn't command dative either when it means the same as English *too* with two "o". As in your example.